# How do extract defect report from Visual studio Team services?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to extract defect report from Visual studio Team services as we do from ALM
Please advise as how to perform this

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS doesn’t have the reports like TFS, but it [integrates with Power BI](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/overview), also there is [Analytics Marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics) available that provides access to several useful widgets, such as Cycle time.

You can build report in a web app or [VSTS extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview) by using VSTS API, such as [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) if the built-in reports don’t meet your requirement.